# java Intellij error

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

This is my code for my android app which isn't complete

```
package com.example;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private EditText text;
    private EditText text2;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        text2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.result);


    }

    // This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
    // "OnClick property" of the button
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button1:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                RadioButton KelvinButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
                if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                    if(KelvinButton.isChecked())
                    {
                        text2.setText(String.valueOf(convertoKelvin(inputValue)));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button2:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                RadioButton KelvinButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());

                if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (fahrenheitButton.isChecked()) {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
                    if(KelvinButton.isChecked())
                    {
                        text2.setText(String.valueOf(convertoKelvin(inputValue)));
                    }
                }
                break;
            case R.id.button3:
                RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
                RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
                RadioButton KelvinButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
                float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
                if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (KelvinButton.isChecked()) {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    text2.setText(String
                            .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
                    fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
                    celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
                    if(KelvinButton.isChecked())
                    {
                        text2.setText(String.valueOf(convertoKelvin(inputValue)));
                    }
                }
                break;

        }
    }

    // Converts to celsius
    private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
        return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
    }

    // Converts to fahrenheit
    private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
        return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
    }

    private float convertoKelvin(float celsius)
    {
        return ((celsius+273)) ;
    }


}
```

As you can see i have defined my variables each time in very case.If i don't do this i get the error "The value might not have been initialised.What am i doing wrong.

If you were wondering,My code isn't complete.I am suck at this error and will continue once this is fixed

Comment: On which line are you getting that error ?

Comment: at if (celsiusButton.isChecked()).It's not a compiler warning,it's an IDE warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly If you assign values to  `celsiusButton`, `fahrenheitButton` ,`KelvinButton`variables in only one case then you get error.

Reason why this happens is scope of the object initialization. Below is the sample which illustrates what is happening.

```
public void example() {
    String str;
    switch (1) {
    case 1:
        str = "test";// If I initalize here then there is problem since
                        // scope is limited to only this case
        str.toString();
        break;

    default:
        str.toString();// Compilation error here.
        break;
    }
}

public void example() {
    String str = "test";
    switch (1) {
    case 1:
        str.toString();
        break;

    default:
        str.toString();// No error because scope of initialisation is whole
                        // method
        break;
    }
}
```

So you need to define your variables before `switch (view.getId()) {`

And resultant declaration will look like below

```
public void onClick(View view) {
RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
RadioButton KelvinButton=(RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio2);
switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1:
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly, then IntelliJ is warning you about a variable that you're using that may not have been properly initialized.  At a glance, if `onCreate()` isn't called before `onClick()`, then `text` and `text2` would not be initialized.  This could easily be a reason that IntelliJ is a confused.

Comment: Compilation error happens for local variables if they are not initialized. I don't think IntelliJ will violate that rule.